# How to get direction in UIWebView using the googleAPI ?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, webview, ios6

I am developing an application which must give a Direction between the places "a - b" and I don't get the direction in my **UIWebView** as I want...can some one help me?

```
[self setDestinationLocation    :@"an Address"];
[self setSourceLocation         :@"53.219091,6.568096"];

int startMatch = 1;
int numberOfMatches=1;

[self setUrlAddress:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&om=2&daddr=%@&saddr=%@&start=%d&num=%d&view=map&layer=t&t=m",
            [self sourceLocation],
            [self destinationLocation],
            startMatch,
            numberOfMatches
    ]
 ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlAddress]];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[self webView] loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: What do you see on your UIWebview now ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this short example:

```
- (void)getDirections {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (startLat), (startLong) };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { (EndLat), (EndLong) };

    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

}
```

pass your desired latitude,longitude pair. You have the formatted URL, display it on a UIWebView.

try this much,as of now.Tell me what you see.

Comment: I du get the same thing( get the route not the direction on the map graphicaly)

Comment: When you run this code, you will see two points A and B on the map. Simply click on point A and below you will see the turn by turn direction for the route.